# Can you port any kind of a Database into a J2ME application ?? or Is ther any jar file available to perform database operations in any type of phone?

Tags: java-me

I was looking for some kind of a library that could perform database operations on my phone alongwith storing the database itself into my phone using J2ME. ( other than the RecordStore class )

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  In other words, what should the program enable the user to do?  The RecordStore class is all you can really count on.  If you use Android, you get sqlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Tushar Ahirrao has found his answer without our help but for everybody else: J2MEMicroDB is an open source database engine for J2ME

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any such library, even if there would exist one it would also need to be available on the target device so it would be a highly device specific build.

You could find a device that supports SQLite but more than that i cant say.